# Heroku / "fatal: pathspec '.gems' did not match any files"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy one ROR app on Heroku.

As I typed "git push heroku master", I got this :

> -----> Heroku receiving push
>   -----> Rails app detected
>   -----> WARNING: Detected Rails is not declared in either .gems or Gemfile
>          Scheduling the install of Rails 2.3.8.
>          See http://docs.heroku.com/gems for details on specifying gems.

I wanted to know what it meant especially what was behind the "WARNING" message.

On Heroku's website (http://docs.heroku.com/gems) it's said you can fix this issue with the following instructions :

> git add .gems
>   git commit -a -m "added .gems file specifying framework
>   git push heroku master

The problem is when i type "git add .gems", I get this :

> fatal: pathspec '.gems' did not match any files

What do you think i should do ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Have been learning Ubuntu, Heroku+ROR for a few days
OS : Ubuntu 
Ruby : 1.8.7
Rails : 2.3.8

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the `.gems` file first, if it doesn't exist already:

```
$ touch .gems
$ git add .gems
$ git commit
```